# Is it possible to set an MS Access Query on the attached table to get only the records with 'Status' = "CLOSE" on maximium level of 'Rev'?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on an MS Access database and can't find the right SQL syntax for the query to get as result only the records with 'Status' = "CLOSE" on the maximum level of 'Rev'.
The query should show the following result:

| IDBug | MaxDiRev | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | CLOSE |
| 3 | 5 | CLOSE |

Following table 'tblCronologiaB_0' in text-format:

| ID | IDBug | Rev | Status | DateB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | OPEN | 01/06/2023 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | SENT | 01/06/2023 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | CHECK | 05/06/2023 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | OPEN | 06/06/2023 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | SENT | 06/06/2023 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | CHECK | 16/06/2023 |
| 7 | 1 | 3 | CLOSE | 17/06/2023 |
| 23 | 1 | 4 | OPEN | 10/07/2023 |
| 24 | 1 | 4 | SENT | 11/07/2023 |
| 25 | 1 | 5 | CHECK | 20/07/2023 |
| 26 | 1 | 5 | OPEN | 21/07/2023 |
| 8 | 2 | 1 | CHECK | 06/06/2023 |
| 9 | 2 | 1 | OPEN | 07/06/2023 |
| 10 | 2 | 1 | SENT | 07/06/2023 |
| 11 | 2 | 2 | CHECK | 17/06/2023 |
| 12 | 2 | 2 | CLOSE | 18/06/2023 |
| 13 | 3 | 1 | OPEN | 11/07/2023 |
| 14 | 3 | 1 | SENT | 11/07/2023 |
| 15 | 3 | 2 | CHECK | 15/07/2023 |
| 16 | 3 | 2 | OPEN | 16/07/2023 |
| 17 | 3 | 2 | SENT | 16/07/2023 |
| 18 | 3 | 3 | CHECK | 26/07/2023 |
| 19 | 3 | 3 | OPEN | 27/07/2023 |
| 20 | 3 | 4 | SENT | 28/07/2023 |
| 21 | 3 | 5 | CHECK | 10/08/2023 |
| 22 | 3 | 5 | CLOSE | 12/08/2023 |
| 27 | 4 | 1 | OPEN | 12/07/2023 |
| 30 | 4 | 1 | SENT | 14/07/2023 |
| 28 | 5 | 1 | OPEN | 12/07/2023 |
| 31 | 5 | 1 | SENT | 14/07/2023 |
| 29 | 6 | 1 | OPEN | 13/07/2023 |
| 32 | 6 | 1 | SENT | 14/07/2023 |

Using the following SQL statement query, I get as result also IDBug = 1 with MaxDiRev = 3, because Status is "CLOSE", even if 3 is not the maximum of Rev filed for IDBug = 1:

```
SELECT tblCronologiaB_0.IDBug, Max(tblCronologiaB_0.Rev) AS MaxDiRev, tblCronologiaB_0.Status
FROM tblCronologiaB_0
GROUP BY tblCronologiaB_0.IDBug, tblCronologiaB_0.Status
HAVING (((tblCronologiaB_0.Status)="CLOSE"));
```

Can someone please help on this?
Many thanks

Comment: Data should be provided as formatted text table and/or DDL. Also show desired output of sample as another text table.

Comment: table in text format loaded, thank you.

Comment: No need to leave image. And still not showing desired output.

Comment: Question content amended: hope this is more clear than before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a correlated subquery using TOP N. Only IDBug 2, 3 will return.

```
SELECT tblCronologiaB_0.* FROM tblCronologiaB_0 
WHERE ID IN(
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM tblCronologiaB_0 AS Dupe 
    WHERE Dupe.IDBug = tblCronologiaB_0.IDBug ORDER BY Dupe.ID DESC) 
AND Status="CLOSE";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @June7.
Anyhow I get an error message from Access:
(transalted from italian)
"The reference to the specified field 'IDBug' may be to multiple tables listed in the FROM clause of the SQL statement."

Comment: Sorry, change IDBug in outer query to `tblCronologiaB_0.IDBug` or use `SELECT tblCronologiaB_0.*, MREV`. Edited answer.

Comment: now is running, thank you, but I received back as result also IDBug = 1 that hasn't Status = 'CLOSE' on its maximum Rev (that is 5).
I'd like Access to find the record (if available) for each IDBug, at its own maximum Rev, that is having Status = 'CLOSE'.
It is something like you can make with filters in Excel:
1st filter for the IDBug;
2nd filter for Maximum of Rev for that IDBug;
3rd filter Status = 'CLOSE'

Comment: In the meantime I've found a solution but think there should be an easier string.

SELECT R1.IDBug, Max(R1.Rev) AS MaxDiRev, (SELECT R2.Status FROM tblCronologiaB_0 as R2 WHERE R2.IDBug = R1.IDBug AND R2.Rev = (SELECT Max(R3.Rev) FROM tblCronologiaB_0 as R3 WHERE R3.IDBug = R1.IDBug) AND R2.Status = 'CLOSE') AS Stato
FROM tblCronologiaB_0 AS R1
GROUP BY R1.IDBug
HAVING ((((SELECT R2.Status FROM tblCronologiaB_0 as R2 WHERE R2.IDBug = R1.IDBug AND R2.Rev = (SELECT Max(R3.Rev) FROM tblCronologiaB_0 as R3 WHERE R3.IDBug = R1.IDBug) AND R2.Status = 'CLOSE')) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY R1.IDBug;

Comment: Okay, with your query I have an example of desired output. Would have been helpful to have that in your question. See revised answer.

Comment: That's a great solution, thank you for your help! I've just made some small changings to get the required information as outputs: 
SELECT R1.IDBug, R1.Rev, R1.Status
FROM tblCronologiaB_0 as R1
WHERE (((R1.ID) In (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM tblCronologiaB_0 AS R2 
    WHERE R2.IDBug = R1.IDBug ORDER BY R2.ID DESC)) AND ((R1.Status)="CLOSE"));